# Where to find Google Cloud Compute Cost Breakdown?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I am trying out Google Cloud Compute, which is a totally different from Microsoft Azure, and I'm having difficulty getting the hang of it.

For instance, where do you find the Google Cloud Compute equivalent of Microsoft Azure's cost breakdown?

Please see this screenshot, and you'll know what I'm talking about: [Microsoft Azure's Price Breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fogy.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your payments breakdown, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/, then choose your billing account. Go to "Payment overview" to see your invoices, download PDFs, etc.

If you want to see services that are not yet billed, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/billing/unbilledinvoice and choose a project in question.