# Google Cloud: how to get billing breakdown (compute time, build time, etc.)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Edit (solution), summarized from answer below:

Cloud console > billing > reports > **preset views** (at right) > current month **all services** (instead of "all projects")

--

I'm trying to see which aspects of my project are incurring costs, **specifically the cost for build time and compute time on a given day.**

I can access my invoice, but this only gives my a total per day per project, without itemizing resource costs.

There's this question: [Where to find Google Cloud Compute Cost Breakdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366414/where-to-find-google-cloud-compute-cost-breakdown)

But that doesn't point to specifics.  Is there not some easy way to just see a chart or cost list per project?

I see in the docs there used to be a way to download a file, which is now deprecated (!).

Answer (score 2):

In the Reports page, within the Filters panel on the right hand-side, there's a `Group by` dropdown - select `SKU`.